# Implementation of ECC in Java

Tags: java, jce, elliptic-curve

While trying to encrypt a given input using Elliptic Curve Cryptography in Java I'm using the following algorithms for generating the cipher and the key:

KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA");
Cipher           cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ECIES");

Now as expected, the cipher isn't accepting the keys generated by the ECDSA algorithm. I get the error as - must be passed IE key.

I searched for the ciphers being supported by these 2 methods here: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher

Unfortunately no else algo is supported for ECC. Has anyone used ECC generated keys to encrypt/decrypt an input? Which algo should I use for both so that they don't clash with each other?

Answer (score 1):

According to http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#KeyPairGenerator, you need to pass "EC" for an instance of the KeyPairGenerator for ECC.

Comment: Even when I use EC, the cipher using ECIES doesn't recognise it as a valid key.

Comment: @Rookie_22 Install Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files 8 is required to run libsignal.
Download link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

Answer (score 1):

Also for a more feature-rich cryptography implementation take a look at [Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).